# How to speed up animation-list in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, animation

Currently, I'm programming an app that uses an animation-list to display a set of frames for a button being colored in. It looks like

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mathematics_0" android:duration="1" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mathematics_1" android:duration="1" />   
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mathematics_28" android:duration="1" />
    </animation-list>
```

I have the individual items in the animation set to a duration of 1, but it doesn't appear to have any large effect on the speed. If I'm understanding the animation duration documentation, it should be in milliseconds which means my 29 item animation-list should take 29 milliseconds. However, it appears to be taking much longer than 29 milliseconds (somewhere around 500ms or so). What would be the best way of speeding up the animation even more, if that's possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivAnimImage);
 AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)img.getDrawable();
 frameAnimation.setCallback(img);
 frameAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
 frameAnimation.start();
```

in anim file

```
<animation-list   android:id="@+id/my_animation" android:oneshot="false" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="15" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame2" android:duration="15" />

 </animation-list>
```

Comment: So this would result in an animation that would take 30 milliseconds?